# I am building a flutter app, my code was working fine until i got thrown by this exception called "Exception caused by Widgets Library"

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

when i run my app it probably comes up with a red screen printing invalid Argument(s). I think the problem is with my code, please point out if any or if this is some other problem.

```
I/flutter ( 4556): EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
I/flutter ( 4556): The following ArgumentError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#34ff8):
I/flutter ( 4556): Invalid argument(s)
I/flutter ( 4556): 
I/flutter ( 4556): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4556): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:145:60)
I/flutter ( 4556): #1      _MyAppState.build (package:colors_pick/main.dart:74:31)
I/flutter ( 4556): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4039:27)
I/flutter ( 4556): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3933:15)
I/flutter ( 4556): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3730:5)
I/flutter ( 4556): #5      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2340:33)
I/flutter ( 4556): #6      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:20)
I/flutter ( 4556): #7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
I/flutter ( 4556): #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter ( 4556): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter ( 4556): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter ( 4556): #12     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 4556): #13     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 4556): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter ( 4556): (elided one frame from package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 4556):
```

i have tried running flutter doctor,flutter clean. but didn't help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
//import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  List _Colors = [Colors.black,Colors.white,Colors.green,Colors.red,Colors.lightBlueAccent,Colors.yellow,
  Colors.purple,Colors.orange,Colors.cyan,Colors.grey, Colors.pinkAccent, Colors.brown,
  Colors.lightGreen,Colors.indigo,Colors.teal

  ];

  int index,indbtn = 0;
  Random random = new Random();


  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  var Score = 0;
  int ind=0;

  void changeIndex(int ic) {
    setState((){
      debugPrint('Index is :  $index');


      bool ans =  index == ic ? true : false ;
      if(ans)
        Score= Score+10;
      else
        Score = Score-10 ;
      index =  random.nextInt(4);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Colors Pick',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,

          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        body: Column(children:<Widget> [

          Padding(

            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child:ClipRRect(

              borderRadius : BorderRadius.circular(700.0),
              child : AnimatedContainer(

                width : 150.0,height: 150.0,
                color: _Colors[index],
                duration : Duration(seconds: 0),
              ),
            ),),

          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),

            child: Container(
              width: 320.0,
              height: 100.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0, bottom:0),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              ),
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  new Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text("Score           :  $Score"),
                    ),
                  ],),
                  new Row (
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0, top:0),
                        child: Text("Level            :  1"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row (
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0, top:8.0),
                        child: Text("High Score  :  $Score"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),



          new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,top: 20.0,right: 20.0),
            child:new Row(children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(child: OutlineButton(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16.0,top:30.0,right:16.0 ,bottom: 30.0 ),
                  child: Text('First'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  ind = 0;
                  changeIndex(ind);
                }, //callback when button is clicked
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black87, //Color of the border
                  style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
                  width: 0.1, //width of the border
                ),), ),
              new Expanded(child: OutlineButton(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16.0,top:30.0,right:16.0 ,bottom: 30.0 ),
                  child: Text('SecondButton'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  ind = 1;
                  changeIndex(ind);
                }, //callback when button is clicked
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black87, //Color of the border
                  style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
                  width: 0.1, //width of the border
                ),), ),

            ],),


          ),
          new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right: 20.0),
            child:new Row(children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(child: OutlineButton(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16.0,top:30.0,right:16.0 ,bottom: 30.0 ),
                  child: Text('Vutton'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  ind = 2;
                  changeIndex(ind);
                }, //callback when button is clicked
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black87, //Color of the border
                  style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
                  width: 0.1, //width of the border
                ),), ),
              new Expanded(child: OutlineButton(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16.0,top:30.0,right:16.0 ,bottom: 30.0 ),
                  child: Text('Hell'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  ind = 3;
                  changeIndex(ind);
                }, //callback when button is clicked
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black87, //Color of the border
                  style: BorderStyle.solid, //Style of the border
                  width: 0.1, //width of the border
                ),), ),
            ],),


          ),
        ],),
        bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 50.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: new BottomAppBar(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home,),
                    onPressed: (){}),
                new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search,),
                    onPressed: null),
                new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.school,),
                    onPressed: null),
                new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.people_outline,),
                    onPressed: null),
                new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.school,),
                    onPressed: null)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: When did this error exactly occur?

Comment: Just a guess but try changing `List _Colors =` to `var _Colors =`

Comment: i was writing a new function for creating random numbers and to perform something with it. after that when i tried running this happened,also i was trying to get color name from colors by trying out _colors[index].tostring() which didn't happen

Comment: changing to var didn't help